# How can I run a (16-bit) .COM executable that has been renamed to .COS?

Tags: windows, command-line, ms-dos, file-extension, 16-bit

I'm trying to run a couple of 16-bit legacy DOS programs from a standard Windows XP DOS prompt. The problem is that the file extensions have been renamed from .COM to .COS and they are stored on read-only media and I can't copy them (special environment).

Any tips on how to invoke such files despite the weird extension? If they had been 32-bit EXEs, it wouldn't have been an issue running them even without their proper extensions, but with these COM files, I'm unable to find a way to run them.

Comment: You should add more details about the environment, especially about your "special environment".

Comment: Figure out a way to burn a new copy of the media. They were created in some manner.

Comment: The command prompt in Windows XP is **not** DOS. [They aren't the same thing](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 4):

Look what I can do :-) (just did this in an XP DOS box):

```
C:\>md test

C:\>cd test

C:\test>xcopy c:\windows\system32\tree.com
C:\windows\system32\tree.com
1 File(s) copied

C:\test>md t1

C:\test>md t2

C:\test>tree
Volume in drive C is OSDisk
Volume Serial Number is 0006EFC4 9654:5A1E
C:.
├───t1
└───t2

C:\test>ren tree.com tree.cos

C:\test>tree.cos
Volume in drive C is OSDisk
Volume Serial Number is 0006EFC4 9654:5A1E
C:.
├───t1
└───t2

C:\test>ren tree.cos newname.cos

C:\test>newname.cos
Volume in drive C is OSDisk
Volume Serial Number is 0006EFC4 9654:5A1E
C:.
├───t1
└───t2

C:\test>
```

I.e. you obviously can execute cos files if you explicitely name the extension at the DOS prompt.

Comment: Nope; that is **incorrect**. The reason that works is because `tree.com` is not actually a .COM file, it is a .EXE file with a `.com` extension for backward-compatibility (as are almost all of the .COM files in Windows for quite a few versions now). If it were a true .COM file, it would have been opened with the default “all-files” program, or if none is set, then you would have been prompted with the *Open With* dialog box.

Comment: True. Cool. Uncool that a simple type tree.com reveals that is has an MZ exe signature. Doh. So what would be the correct answer? "Not at all"?

Answer (score 4):

Ok.  I have figured it out.  I think, anyway.  This takes advantage of the fact that DOS .COM files are just binary images with a 0x100 byte header, with the first couple bytes being a `JMP 0x0100` (hopefully I'm right about that) and the old DOS utility `debug` which exists in XP.

- open command prompt
- `cd` to directory containing .COS files
- `debug` <kbd>enter</kbd>
- You are now at the `debug.exe` prompt (just a dash)
- Type `n{name of your .COS file, including extension}` - substituting appropriately.  For example, for FILE.COS type `nfile.cos`, then <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Type `l` (for load) then <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Type `g` (for go) then <kbd>enter</kbd>

Let me know how that goes.  I loaded `C:\windows\system32\tree.com` but evidently it's really an `.EXE` (says this cannot be run in DOS mode).  Good luck.

(BTW I *just* read the stuff about tree.com up there, whoops!)

Comment: Yup, that could do the trick. Of course it’s a real pain and some serious limits like not being runnable from a batch file or the *Run* dialog. Not being able to copy them sure is frustrating isn’t it? `:-(`

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid that it is not possible to do what you want under the circumstances that you have outlined. Executable files are treated specially (due to their ability to infect a system), so Windows will not let you just run any old file as an executable.

The `PATHEXT` environment variable tells Windows what programs are "executable" and can be "run", but there are limits. Open a command-prompt and append `.cos` to `pathext` and try to run one of the `.cos` files:

```
> set pathext=.cos;%pathext%
> foobar.cos
```

You will see that either the default "all files" program runs, or if none is configured, that the *Open With* dialog is presented. Why? Because Windows restricts what can be run for safty reasons. You should be able to register `.cos` files as executable (like `.py`, `.pl`, etc.), but even then, it may not be possible since a `.py` or `.pl` file is actually just a **document** that is opened by a program, not an actual *executable*.

Another option might be to try to create an association whereby you tell the system that `.cos` files are `comfiles`. However, the quick test I just attempted did not work and Windows complained that it is not an executable file and returned *access denied*.