# What is the difference between CMD and Command prompt in windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, cmd.exe, ms-dos

Until now, I never thought (and never observed) that `cmd` and `command` are two different things. Well, *are they?*

Take a look at this pic:

[image: Screenshot of cmd.exe and command.com in 32-bit Windows 7]

Actually, I usually open `cmd` from the Run dialog whenever I want to command-line (for Git/ VIM). So, I customized the display position, font, color, etc. Today, I, for a change, typed `command` in Run instead of `cmd` and found that there is something new on my window. *It has "DOS" in its window.*

So, obviously there should be difference between `cmd` and `command`. I would like to know

1. The difference between them.
2. Why Microsoft separated them (Unix & Linux has only one shell by default, Bash).

Comment: I would assume `command.com` is the legacy 16bit version (only available on 32bit installations). It doesn't exist on my 64bit version of Windows 7.

Comment: UNIX and Linux have *more than just one shell* available.  The default shell is typically Bash.

Comment: @ephsmith that's what I said..

Comment: Note that the phrase "command prompt" could technically be used to refer to either command.exe or cmd.exe, but in practice is almost always used to mean cmd.exe.

Comment: Unix has a total of four shell these are csh, ksh, bash, zsh.

Comment: @Deb that's absolutely not true. There are lots of shells for Unix like sh, ash, dash, bash, csh, ksh, pdksh, mksh, tcsh, powershell, es, fish, wish, scsh, ksh93, ksh88, Qshell... POSIX only requires `sh`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## TL;DR

When you run a 32-bit console program, it is executed by `cmd`; when you run a 16-bit console program, it is executed by `command`.

## Details

Windows XP includes a subsystem to support older 16-bit applications.

Old 16-bit applications are available as both DOS and Windows programs. DOS programs by their nature are console applications and run in what looks like the command-prompt. However 32-bit Windows console applications are very similar and look the same.

The command processor/interpreter `cmd` has several purposes:

- To execute 32-bit text Windows console program
- To provide and handle various command-line functions (`dir`, `copy`, etc.)
- Interpret and execute batch files (DOS compatible `.bat` files and NT compatible `.cmd` files)

When you run an old 16-bit console program, it is executed by the NTVDM (Windows NT Virtual DOS Machine). It provides an emulated DOS system (hence the *virtual DOS machine*) which is similar to running a dedicated virtual machine software, except the emulation layer is simpler. `command` is a 16-bit version of the command-interpreter that is much closer to actual DOS than `cmd.exe` which is actually a Windows program (and has the Windows PE header, unlike `command.com` which has the DOS MZ header).

`command` has the same purposes as `cmd` except that it only supports 16-bit programs. In addition, it does not support `.cmd` files and has fewer built-in commands and is more limited in its syntax (`cmd` is a newer, more modern, more advanced command-line interpreter, similar to [4DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4DOS)).

However, it supports graphical DOS programs (like old games), but the success of running them depends on the video-card drivers and the nature of the program. There are numerous sites that offer [various tricks](http://buildxp.deathmask.net/) to get DOS games to run on Windows (though success on Vista and up is usually more limited than on XP).

It should be noted that 64-bit versions of Windows have completely dropped support of 16-bit programs, and so do not include `command` at all, so neither DOS nor Windows 16-bit programs will run and instead will throw a (misleading) [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99tND.png).

**Technical notes**

`command.com` has a `.com` extension for backwards compatibility with DOS programs, but like most of the other Windows versions of external DOS commands, internally, it is actually a Windows PE `.exe` file. This provides the interesting observation that while Windows uses the extension as an indicator of how to handle most file-types, for executable ones, it ignores the extension and looks at its contents (otherwise an `.exe` would not work if treated as a `.com`). [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/396191/) relates to this effect.

Comment: While you can of course run a 32-bit console program from cmd.exe, you don't have to.  If you double-click a console-mode executable file, it doesn't run "inside" cmd.exe.  Similarly, command.exe isn't really the same thing as the NTVDM.

Comment: I hate starting a sentence with a command-name.

Comment: *> command.exe isn't really the same thing as the NTVDM*   No, but it is a *part* of it, along with several DLLs (I learned this the hard way while trying to get 16-bit console apps to work on an XP system).

Comment: "DOS programs by their nature are [console applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_application)" – Why would you say this? Are non-command line non-TUI DOS apps 'unnatural' in some way? :)

Comment: `Why would you say this? Are non-command line non-TUI DOS apps 'unnatural' in some way?`   Sort of. In 9x, they were fine, but graphical apps (e.g., games) no longer work properly if at all in XP+, so the vast majority of DOS apps that are run on Windows (natively) these days are indeed command-line tools instead of full-fledge, graphical apps. On 64-bit machines, 16-bit apps don’t run natively at all, but even 32-bit apps are usually console apps, especially since [Vista dropped support](http://superuser.com/questions/314675/) for [fullscreen consoles](http://superuser.com/questions/160134/).

Answer (score 8):

> Unlike COMMAND.COM, which is a DOS program, cmd.exe is a native Windows application usually running in Win32 console. This allows it to take advantage of features available to native programs on the platform that are otherwise unavailable to DOS programs.

also...

> Both the OS/2 and the Windows NT versions of cmd.exe have more detailed error messages than the blanket "Bad command or file name" (in the case of malformed commands) of command.com.

That's from [this informative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMMAND.COM) Wikipedia article.

There is mention of how older command.com commands have been rolled into newer cmd.exe functionality... for example...

> the functionality of deltree (command.com) was rolled into rd (cmd.exe) in the form of the /s parameter

So, feel free to read up.

Answer (score 1):

They're different shells so the syntax and many other things are different. Some good information has been provided in other answers so here is a summary of the syntax differences. For more details read my answer here: [Are the Command Prompt and MS-DOS the same thing?](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386)

- `command.com` doesn't support grouping commands with `()`
- `command.com` has no functions or local scope
- `command.com` doesn't have an escape character which is `^` in `cmd.exe`
- `command.com` doesn't support `if cmdextversion` and `if defined`, also no numeric and case-insensitive string comparison `if [/i] string1 compare-op string2`
- `command.com` doesn't have command history and command argument completion
- `command.com` doesn't support *indirect expansion* (e.g. `call set %%var%suffix%=string`) of variables or *delayed expansion* (e.g. `echo !var%suffix%!`)
- `command.com` doesn't support advanced string manipulation: no [`~xxxV` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5034076/995714), no substring `%variable:~num1,num2%` or string replacement `%variable:str=newstr%`
- The `set` command in `command.com` doesn't  support partial variable name matching, and no `set /a`, `set /p` or `set "var=value"`
- `command.com` doesn't support `%*` which expand to the whole command line
- `command.com` has no `for /d`, `for /r`, `for /l` or `for /f`
- `command.com` doesn't have [special environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51841636/995714) like `%CD% %DATE% %TIME% %RANDOM% %ERRORLEVEL% %CMDEXTVERSION% %CMDCMDLINE% %HIGHESTNUMANODENUMBER%`
- `command.com` doesn't have `pushd/popd` or `cd /d`. And obviously it doesn't support `cd path with spaces` and `cd "path with spaces"` like `cmd.exe`
- `command.com` doesn't have the [`color`](https://superuser.com/q/952425/241386) or `title` command